# Get the path of an HTTP Request from another component

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to let JMeter crowl my website to ensure a realistic stress test. I was able to extract the URLs from the home page and iterate on them. So I have a regular expression feeding a ForEach loop.
Now I am not able to let an HTTP Request take the output of the loop (Defined as  a variable with a name) as its path.
Is there a general approach to setting the path of such a request. JMeter is taking something like:

${MyVar}

set in the path of the request as a string and is not replacing it with the actual value.

Comment: It means the value of the variable was not set. Put Debug Sampler and / or use RegEx tester to make sure extraction is right. Hard to tell anything more specific from the details you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Given your Regular Expression Extractor and ForEach Controller configurations are correct everything should work fine. If you need any assistance with this provide the following screenshots:

1. Regular Expression Extractor configuration
2. [Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) or [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) output in the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener showing several generated JMeter Variables
3. ForEach Controller configuration
4. HTTP Request sampler configuration (i.e. where do you put the variable)

---

Be aware that you can mimic crawling the site more easily using [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) the relevant configuration would be as simple as

[image: JMeter HTML Link Parser Config]

See [How to Spider a Site with JMeter - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-spider-site-jmeter-tutorial) to learn more about simulating websites crawling.